# Why would anyone purchase Windows Server directly from Microsoft?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I was [looking on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=Windows+Server+2012&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.XWindows+Server+2012+datacenter&_nkw=Windows+Server+2012+datacenter&_sacat=0) and I realized that there are people selling copies of Windows Server 2012 Datacenter for way cheaper than retail.  I assume that they are just reselling volume licenses or something.

What pitfalls exist when purchasing a license in this manner?  Why would anyone pay $2500 for a copy of datacenter from MS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: I guess these have fallen from the back of a truck on some lonesome road ...

Comment: Guys, I don't think this is a dupe of the software licensing question. He's not asking about license terms, he's asking about the possible pitfalls of purchasing license from black market channels, which I think, is probably legitimate. I've edited this question to remove the legal aspect (which *is* off topic here) and voted to re-open.

Answer (score 14):

I wouldn't buy from eBay, you don't have the same counterfeit or audit protection as buying directly from an authorized reseller like CDW, Dell, HP, Software One, etc.

I agree that most organizations should never buy direct from Microsoft, but you *should* buy direct from an authorized reseller. Getting your server licenses from eBay is like getting your underwear from eBay. You don't know where it's been or who's already used it. It might be fine for some people, but it's not for me! By purchasing from eBay, you run the risk of getting a TechNet/MSDN key, which is not meant for production, and you'll fail a license audit if you're even in that unfortunate situation. Plus, just look at the first few links. The sellers can't even use proper punctuation or capitalization. Are you willing to risk the integrity of your server infrastructure on someone that doesn't capitalize `"I"`?

Also, just so you know, the [list retail cost of 2012 Datacenter](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/buy.aspx) is $4,809 USD per 2-socket license, not $2,500. If you can find them from a *legitimate* reseller for $2,500 USD, buy it now!

Comment: Some of those Datacenter licenses actually appear to be Standard licenses. Others look like they were taken from licenses shipped with OEM hardware. Still others I couldn't tell you what, or if, they're selling the product described. Some might even be MSDN keys. I just wouldn't do eBay for this at all.

Comment: Some of them appear to be unopened copies (especially the CALs) and thus idk how they can be fake.  If they were it won't activate.  I doubt MS would audit a smaller firm and even if so one could at least prove they acted in good faith.  Plus if it's already been used you just file a paypal dispute and get your $ back.

Comment: +1 for the underwear analogy.

Comment: @oooooo3333 the choice is obviously yours to make, but there is a long process that an organization goes through to become an authorized reseller. There's a reason that these are on eBay at prices so low that no authorized (reputable) reseller could possibly match it. Make your own decision, but if something is too good to be true, it usually is.

Comment: @MDMarra - Is that process more of "corporate red tape" than anything?  The reselling company now has a nice official buzzword they can put on their products.  I understand it cost a lot to become authorized (and this is reflected in the price of the product) and big corps who can only buy from approved vendors love this, but what does it mean to me as a consumer?  Kind of like buying a chevy from an "authorized chevy dealer" vs "joes car lot".  It gives you a peace of mind to buy from the authorized dealer, but when you really peel back the label the joes car lot car may be just as good.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't make any distinction between intentional and unintentional piracy and neither does law enforcement. Pleading ignorance or that you acted in good faith isn't a defense that will put you in good stead.

Comment: Joe's car lot might be just as good but if you purchase a stolen car from Joe's car lot then it's going to be confiscated and you'll be out of a car and the money you spent to purchase it. The law doesn't "reimburse" you the money you spent unintentionally purchasing stolen or counterfeit goods.

Comment: `Is that process more of "corporate red tape" than anything?` - No. I've explained that already. You have counterfeit protection and audit protection when you purchase through an authorized reseller. `The reselling company now has a nice official buzzword they can put on their products.` It takes a large investment (time & money) to become an authorized reseller. Don't you think companies would avoid this expense if possible? Your car analogy doesn't hold up because there aren't pirated cars, or cars with TechNet keys that are only authorized to drive on certain roads.

Comment: @oooooo3333 Buy whatever you like, but I've never in my life seen anyone purchase licensing from eBay in a proper corporate environment. Too much risk, too little reward. If you can afford the hardware to take advantage of Datacenter licensing (virtualized at 6:1 or denser) you can surely afford a proper license, right?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Can an organization resell a license?  Let's say I purchase a server with server 2012 pre installed

Comment: No, they cannot. A preinstalled OEM license cannot be transferred per the EULA, except in countries where such restrictions are not legal. In the USA, they cannot and you wouldn't be considered the valid owner of that license unless you also own the hardware it originally shipped on. *This* is the kind of reason why you always go through a legit reseller. There are too many gotchas to licensing that the average admin isn't equipped to handle. There are entire certification exams on MS licensing that these authorized resellers have to take to ensure that you're getting exactly what you need.

Answer (score -2):

I think the reason is. It possible duplicate the license key. who can say exactly the seller is not selling same serial twice

Comment: Because it wouldn't activate I assume and then I just file a paypal dispute and give him bad FB.  No harm done there.